# Efficient Scala idiomatic way to pick top 85 percent of sorted values?

Tags: scala

Given a non-increasing list of numbers, I want to pick top 85% of values in the list. Here is how I am currently doing it.

```
scala> val a = Array(8.60, 6.85, 4.91, 3.45, 2.74, 2.06, 1.53, 0.35, 0.28, 0.12)
a: Array[Double] = Array(8.6, 6.85, 4.91, 3.45, 2.74, 2.06, 1.53, 0.35, 0.28, 0.12)

scala> val threshold = a.sum * 0.85
threshold: Double = 26.2565

scala> val successiveSums = a.tail.foldLeft(Array[Double](a.head)){ case (x,y) => x ++ Array(y + x.last) }
successiveSums: Array[Double] = Array(8.6, 15.45, 20.36, 23.81, 26.549999999999997, 28.609999999999996, 30.139999999999997, 30.49, 30.77, 30.89)

scala> successiveSums.takeWhile( x => x <= threshold )
res40: Array[Double] = Array(8.6, 15.45, 20.36, 23.81)

scala> val size = successiveSums.takeWhile( x => x <= threshold ).size
size: Int = 4

scala> a.take(size)
res41: Array[Double] = Array(8.6, 6.85, 4.91, 3.45)
```

I want improve its

- performance
- code-size

Any suggestions ?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On code size, consider this oneliner,

```
a.take( a.scanLeft(0.0)(_+_).takeWhile( _ <= a.sum * 0.85 ).size - 1 )
```

Here `scanLeft` accumulates additions.

On performance, tagging intermediate values may help not to recompute same operations, namely

```
val threshold = a.sum * 0.85
val size = a.scanLeft(0.0)(_+_).takeWhile( _ <= threshold ).size - 1
a.take( size )
```

Comment: `scanLeft` seems perfect !

Answer (score 2):

There is some space for improvement in elm's answer:
1) You don't need to compute sum 2 times.
2) You can avoid creation of additional collection with `takeWhile` method and use `indexWhere` instead.

```
val sums = a.scanLeft(0.0)(_ + _)
a.take(sums.indexWhere(_ > sums.last * 0.85) - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no library method that will do exactly what you want.  Generally if you want something that performs well, you'd use a tail-recursive method both to find the sum and to find the point where the 85th percentile of the total sum is crossed.  Something like

```
def threshold(
  xs: Array[Double], thresh: Double,
  i: Int = 0, sum: Double = 0
) {
  val next = sum + x(i)
  if (next > thresh) xs.take(i)
  else threshold(xs, thresh, i+1, next)
}
```

Comment: I was thinking in terms of folds, and recursive method seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case I would make a little use of mutable state. See the code below:

```
val a = Array(8.60, 6.85, 4.91, 3.45, 2.74, 2.06, 1.53, 0.35, 0.28, 0.12)

def f(a: Array[Double]) = {
  val toGet = a.sum * 0.85
  var sum = 0.0
  a.takeWhile(x => {sum += x; sum <= toGet })
}

println(f(a).deep) //Array(8.6, 6.85, 4.91, 3.45)
```

In my opinion it's acceptable because function `f` does not have any side effects

Comment: I wanted to avoid `var` too.